# Android Q: Can I set the default directory once and save files without file picker?

Tags: android, android-10.0, storage-access-framework

I have a question about saving files in Android Q. As far as I understand it, if I want to save a file to a public directory and want it to be accessible by other apps I need to use the Storage Access Framework and the Android's file picker. Can I set up the directory where files will be saved once for example in preference screen without having to choose the directory every time a file is saving?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The new Storage Access Framework should have an option to define a default external path to save a file and my users don't be forced to pick a location outside from app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I set up the directory where files will be saved once... without having to choose the directory every time a file is saving?

On Android 5.1+, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to allow the user to choose a base directory. From there, you can:

- Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` representing that tree
- Use that `DocumentFile` to create a child tree (e.g., directory)
- Use `ContentResolver` and `takePersistableUriPermission()` to have long-term access to your new child tree
- Use `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile` to put content into that child tree

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is there any way to get the real path from the receiver Uri? I use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent in Preferences screen and want to display the chosen path as a summary.

Comment: @Piotr: "but is there any way to get the real path from the receiver Uri?" -- no, because there is no "real path" for a `Uri`. The document does not have to be a file on the filesystem of the device. It could be the contents of a `BLOB` column in a database. It could be generated on the fly, the way that this Web page that you are reading is. It could be content that is stored on the Internet and is downloaded on the fly. You have no way of knowing.

Comment: So is there any other way working on Android Q, to let the user choose a directory and save the path that it can be later retrieved and displayed as a summary of the edittextpreference? Maybe not using the Storage Access Framework but something else?

Comment: @Piotr: You can build your own create-a-directory UI that limits the user to places that you can read/write on the filesystem (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`). Or, you can persist the `Uri` (after using `ContentResolver` and `takePersistableUriPermission()`) that you get from the Storage Access Framework and use that `Uri` for your content I/O. Worrying about the summary of a `Preference` should not be a priority -- getting a data persistence approach that works in general should be the priority.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is not possible with Android 10 Q beta.

You can create files like as you said using

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` &

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` till API 28.

This is deprecated from API 29. i.e Android 10 Q.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)